# How to compile file using scheme2c

Tags: scheme, linker-errors

I am trying to compile a Scheme program using [scheme2c](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/scheme2c) (the DEC Scheme->C Compiler). This is the program `hello.sc`:

```lisp
(module hello (main run-main))

(define (run-main)
  (display "Hello!")
  (newline))
```

I tried to compile the program using `scc hello.sc`, but the compilation fails with these linker error messages:

```
hello.sc:
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scinit.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(apply.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(callcc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `sc_display' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(cio.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(heap.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(objects.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scdebug.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(sceval.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scexpand.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scexpnd1.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scexpnd2.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(screp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scrt1.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scrt2.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scrt3.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scrt4.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scrt5.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scrt6.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scrt7.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/scheme2c/libs2c.a(scqquote.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I compile a Scheme program using `scc`?

(scheme2c version 2012.10.14 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS)

Comment: Why that implementation? The official homepage doesn't seem to exist any more and mirrors of the source I found seem to suggest real development on it stopped in 1993. If you want a scheme that compiles to C, there are modern ones like chicken.

Comment: The algorithm is described in an article of Daniel Friedman and in the book of Queinnec (that gave born to bigloo that uses this main idea).  The code is outdated, it is usually implemented by students at master level and I think Daniel Friedman still has an advanced course where, in one of the labs asks to build this translator.  You can find lots of documents to write it alone, anyway.

Comment: Apart from any other consideration your Scheme program isn't R4RS.  What you're trying to do might be interesting archeologically, but probably not practically.

Comment: @Shawn I am reading an old textbook — *Lisp in Small Pieces* by Christian Queinnec. In the makefile of the code provided on the author's website, scheme2c and bigloo are the recommended Scheme implementations for compiling a custom Scheme interpreter that is able to run all the programs in the book.

Comment: Bigloo would be the much better choice between the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIE is enabled by default in Ubuntu's GCC (Ubuntu compiles GCC using the `--enable-default-pie` option).

The problem can be solved by using GCC's `-no-pie` option:

```
$ scc -cc 'gcc -no-pie' hello.sc
hello.sc:
$ ./a.out
Hello!
```